# What is "symmetry" in operations in C?

Tags: c, concept

*K&R* says:

> The unary + is new with the ANSI standard. It was added for symmetry with the unary -.

What is this symmetry in regards to (i.e. it's clearly not *actual*, geometric symmetry) and what is the significance for? Is it important in programming?

Comment: They just mean that there's a unary minus so there might as well be a unary plus. It's not all that relevant to real world programming though I suppose you can could use it for type conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just something that means "in the pattern of", or "as you would reasonably expect given the established pattern". In this particular case `-` is the counterpart to `+`, though there are other pairs like this throughout C.

It means you can do `+2` as well as `-2` and both work. It would be odd, or asymmetric, if `+2` was somehow a syntax error. In fact, in K&R C there are a lot of *odd* things that were later ironed out in the standardization process. This appears to have been one of them.

You don't really *need* a unary `+` operator, you can just omit the `+` and the code compiles fine, but by the same logic you don't need a unary `-` either, you can always do `0 - 5` instead of `-5`, though an oversight like this would seem ridiculous.